# Project Euler #62 + Java 8 streams

Tags: java, programming-challenge, combinatorics, rags-to-riches

(Inspired by  [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92634/finding-the-smallest-cube-for-which-exactly-five-permutations-of-its-digits-are))

> The digits of the cube, 41063625 (345<sup>3</sup>), can be permuted to produce
>   two other cubes:
>
> 56623104 (384<sup>3</sup>) and 66430125 (405<sup>3</sup>). In fact, 41063625 is the
>   smallest cube which has exactly three permutations of its digits which
>   are also cube.
>
> Find the smallest cube for which exactly five permutations of its
>   digits are cube.

My attempt at [#62](https://projecteuler.net/problem=62) using Java 8 streams. I use a custom implementation of [`Spliterator.OfLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfLong.html) (uncreatively named `Generator`) that can be programmatically stopped when the `Map` it is `collect()`-ing to has the desired results. I also chose a custom `Result` class to store related information about the generation. For example, the desired result for this challenge is:

> ```
> ----------
> Size: 5
> Map size: 7772
> Last value: 8384
> Ratio: 1.0787442099845599
> Elapsed time (ms): 16
> Result: 127035954683
> Values: [5027, 7061, 7202, 8288, 8384]
> ----------
> ```

(This is after one "warm-up" round as shown in the `main()` method)

- Is this a feasible approach, or does it really smell 'hack-ish'?
- Any other room for improvement?

My `toKey()` method is based on my answer to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92022/rearranging-numbers-to-get-the-largest-number/92037#92037).

```java
public final class EulerSixtyTwo {
    private static final ToLongFunction<Long> CUBE =
            i -> (long) Math.pow(i.doubleValue(), 3);

    private static Long toKey(Long input) {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        for (long i = CUBE.applyAsLong(input); i != 0; i /= 10) {
            numbers[(int) (i % 10)]++;
        }
        int counter = 0;
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; counter += numbers[i++]) {
            result += (int) ((Math.pow(10, numbers[i]) * i - 1) / 9)
                    * Math.pow(10, counter);
        }
        return Long.valueOf(result);
    }

    private static List<Long> toValue(Long input) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(input));
    }

    private static Result testFor(int limit) {
        if (limit < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Limit cannot be less than 2.");
        }
        Generator generator = new Generator();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Map<Long, List<Long>> map = generator.longStream().boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(EulerSixtyTwo::toKey, EulerSixtyTwo::toValue,
                            (a, b) -> {
                                generator.shouldStop(a.addAll(b) && a.size() == limit);
                                return a;
                            }));
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        return new Result(toKey(generator.getLastValue()), map, elapsedTime);
    }

    private static final int START = 2;
    private static final int END = 21;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // "warm-up"
        IntStream.range(START, END).mapToObj(EulerSixtyTwo::testFor)
                .forEach(v -> {});
        IntStream.range(START, END).mapToObj(EulerSixtyTwo::testFor)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static class Generator implements Spliterator.OfLong {

        private boolean stop = false;
        private long current = 1;

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            return Spliterator.ORDERED + Spliterator.DISTINCT;
        }

        @Override
        public java.util.Spliterator.OfLong trySplit() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(LongConsumer action) {
            action.accept(current++);
            return !stop;
        }

        public void shouldStop(boolean shouldStop) {
            stop = shouldStop;
        }

        public Long getLastValue() {
            return Long.valueOf(current - 1);
        }

        public LongStream longStream() {
            return StreamSupport.longStream(this, false);
        }
    }

    public static class Result {
        private static final String WRAPPER = "\n----------\n";

        private final long answer;
        private final Map<Long, List<Long>> map;
        private final List<Long> values;
        private final long elapsedTime;
        private final String toString;

        public Result(Long key, Map<Long, List<Long>> map, long elapsedTime) {
            this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
            this.values = map.get(key);
            this.answer = CUBE.applyAsLong(values.get(0));
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
            this.toString = getStatistics();
        }

        public long getAnswer() {
            return answer;
        }

        public List<Long> getValues() {
            return values;
        }

        private String getStatistics() {
            int mapSize = map.size();
            long lastValue = values.get(values.size() - 1).longValue();
            double ratio = lastValue / (double) mapSize;
            return Stream.of("Size: " + values.size(), "Map size: " + mapSize,
                            "Last value: " + lastValue, "Ratio: " + ratio,
                            "Elapsed time (ms): " + elapsedTime,
                            "Result: " + getAnswer(),
                            "Values: " + getValues()).map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", WRAPPER, WRAPPER));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return toString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I am very happy, my question inspired someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, I'll sound rather negative and that's mostly caused by my lack of experience with Java 8.

```
private static final ToLongFunction<Long> CUBE =
        i -> (long) Math.pow(i.doubleValue(), 3);
```

While this works fine for small values, you'd get round-off errors when they get bigger (presumably somewhere near `1e16`, which is a lot, but much lower than `Long.MAX_VALUE`; and there are many Euler problem needing `1e18`). And there's no need to take a chance as

```
        i -> i * i * i;
```

is both shorter and cleaner. And faster, too.

```
private static Long toKey(Long input) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for (long i = CUBE.applyAsLong(input); i != 0; i /= 10) {
        numbers[(int) (i % 10)]++;
    }
```

Wouldn't "digits" be a better name?

```
    int counter = 0;
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; counter += numbers[i++]) {
        result += (int) ((Math.pow(10, numbers[i]) * i - 1) / 9)
                * Math.pow(10, counter);
    }
    return Long.valueOf(result);
}
```

That was a mystery to me for a few minutes. I guessed, it should do the same as my below method does (I've solved the problem some time ago)

```
private Multiset<Long> toKey(long x) {
    final Multiset<Long> result = HashMultiset.create();
    for (; x > 0; x /= 10) result.add(x%10);
    return result;
}
```

namely create a key based on the digits while ignoring their order. How I understand it, but it could use quite some comments. I'd simply go for this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         for (j = numbers[i]; j > 0; --j) {
              result = 10 * result + i;
    }
    return Long.valueOf(result);
```

The following looks like you could use Guava's `Multimap`, which allows multiple values per key without such strain:

```
private static List<Long> toValue(Long input) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(input));
}
```

This is fine here, but shouldn't be used for any serious benchmark

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The precision is much worse than for `nanoTime` and mainly: There's no monotonicity guarantee.

```
    Map<Long, List<Long>> map = generator.longStream().boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(EulerSixtyTwo::toKey, EulerSixtyTwo::toValue,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            generator.shouldStop(a.addAll(b) && a.size() == limit);
                            return a;
                        }));
```

I see, you're adding the second value to the first and keeping the first, i.e. computing set union. That's fine, but after `generator.shouldStop` it's the second side-effect in this snippet.

**What's worse:** You should "find the smallest cube for which *exactly* five permutations of its digits are cube" and you're finding one having *at least* five such permutations (AFAIK using `==` doesn't matter as you stop immediately).

```
    return new Result(toKey(generator.getLastValue()), map, elapsedTime);
```

I see, extracting the result from the map would be way more complicated.

```
    public void shouldStop(boolean shouldStop) {
        stop = shouldStop;
    }
```

It's actually a setter, and I'd strongly prefer

```
    public void shouldStop(boolean shouldStop) {
        this.shouldStop = shouldStop;
    }
```

so I don't have to relate the field, the variable, and the setter names.

> Is this a feasible approach, or does it really smell 'hack-ish'?

To me it partly looks like using functional syntax for a not so functional style (I'm not claiming pure functional programming could work for this). I guess, there simply isn't much room for *advantageous* use of Java 8 features in this problem and that's not your fault.

Comment: No worries about sounding negative, I'm glad that I've learned something from your answer! :) Extracting the result from the Map is actually straightforward: once the `List` (as the `Map`'s value) has the desired size, just cube the first element inside my merge function. As mentioned in my question, I have the `Result` class just to store some additional information.

Comment: I also forgot to mention this in my question originally (have edited to included this info), the `toKey()` method is from my answer to this other question about [rearranging numbers to get the largest number](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92022/rearranging-numbers-to-get-the-largest-number/92037#92037). I figured using math will be good enough for the usage here.

Comment: @h.j.k. Good! I also forget to say that I'd avoid `Math.pow` as the problems are not worth it. Use `new int[] {1, 10, 100, ...}` and you'll get more speed and an exception as a bonus if you do anything wrong.